# Is it possible to exclude service access within the same Docker network?

Tags: docker, docker-network, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I am using the `nginx-proxy` image (https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) to automatically configure nginx proxy in front of my services. The corresponding `nginx-proxy` container is running in the `nginx-proxy` network:

```
docker network create nginx-proxy
docker run -d -p 80:80 --network nginx-proxy -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

Now I have several containers which need to be proxied by nginx. To make this work, I need to attach all services to the `nginx-proxy` network. This is required for `nginx-proxy` to access the containers.

But now, all containers can communicate with eachother via this `nginx-proxy` network. This is not desired and possibly unsafe. This breaks the principle of isolation.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Have you tried to use [multiple networks](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy#multiple-networks)?

Comment: @tgogos I am not really sure how this solves my question. If I have two services and both do `docker network connect <network-name-of-service> nginx-proxy`, I believe they still can communicate with each other via `nginx-proxy` as they both have `nginx-proxy` network in common?

Comment: From what I understand by reading that section, you have to create different networks for the services that must be isolated, not only one. You `run` the `nginx-proxy` container and then use `docker network connect` to attach to these networks.

Comment: Yes, I understood it as following. You end up with three networks: `network for service 1`, `network for service 2` and `network for nginx-proxy`. Then you connect `network for service 1` with `network for nginx-proxy` and `network for service 2` with `network for nginx-proxy`. With this construction `network for service 1` can communicatie with `network for service 2` (and vice versa) via `network for nginx-proxy`?

Comment: I see your point, yes they can access each other. How: I've created `net-1` and `net-2`, run the `nginx-proxy` with `--network=net-1` and then attach it also to `net-2` manually. `service-1` and `service-2` **do not have direct** access because they are in different networks/subnets. But, if the requests are sent to the `nginx-proxy` with the correct `host` setting, **they can communicate**.

Comment: I will try this out and keep you updated. Thank you @tgogos.